# PHP Redis not working missing class Redis

Tags: php, redis

I am trying to setup Redis with PHP and it's not working. I have install redis using this resource for php7.4
https://www.prowebtips.com/install-redis-and-php-redis-extension-on-ubuntu/

```
<?php
$redis = new \Redis();
//Connecting to Redis
$redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
$redis->auth('mypassword');

if ($redis->ping()) {
echo "PONGn";
}
```

It's giving this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Redis' not found in /var/www/html/connect.php
```

Comment: Start by reading there [documentation](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).

Comment: @Aditya can you provide more details about your query.